# Scala Slick Driver Logging

Tags: scala, logging, slick

I am using the Slick driver with the following versions:

```
"com.typesafe.slick"  %% "slick"                              % "3.3.1",
"com.typesafe.slick"  %% "slick-hikaricp"                     % "3.3.1"
```

I have imported these in my class `AnimalCounter.scala`

```
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import slick.jdbc.GetResult
```

And, I have the following class structure ...

```
class AnimalCounter {
  val db = Database.forConfig("animaldb")

  def get(a: Animal): Future[Option[Animal]] =
    db.run(....do something......)

  def getOrCreate(a: Animal): Future[Option[Animal]] =
    db.run(....do something......)
}
```

So, how do I setup the inbuilt slick logging to log all DB operations that are happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Change the log config to enable slick logs
 <logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>

Comment: @Vamsi will that config go in the logback.xml file?

Comment: yes, it should be in the logback.xml.

Comment: so I don't have to initialize the logger or anything like that?

Comment: yes, you should be able to see all SQL queries from slick to DB in the logs

Comment: @Vamsi I have been trying to troubleshoot this and it's still not working.

Comment: can you post your logback config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer on how I got it working. I think @vamsi's approach as mentioned above would work too. However, the important thing to remember in my case was that I needed to remove this dependency since it's designed to supress logs from `slick`. So please remove this dependency if you already have it.

`"org.slf4j"           %  "slf4j-nop"                          % "1.7.26"`

And after removing the ^^ dependency, please configure your logback.xml like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%level] [%date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS}] [SLICK] [%logger{1000}] %green(%X{debugId}) %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="${SLICK_LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="slick.basic.BasicBackend.action"          level="${log_action:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.basic.BasicBackend.stream"          level="${log_stream:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.compiler"                           level="OFF" />
    <logger name="slick.compiler.QueryCompiler"             level="OFF" />
    <logger name="slick.compiler.QueryCompilerBenchmark"    level="OFF" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.DriverDataSource"              level="${log_jdbc_driver:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement"         level="${log_jdbc_statement:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.parameter"         level="${log_jdbc_parameter:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark"         level="${log_jdbc_bench:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result"       level="${log_jdbc_result:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcModelBuilder"              level="${log_createModel:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.memory.HeapBackend"                 level="${log_heap:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.memory.QueryInterpreter"            level="${log_interpreter:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.relational.ResultConverterCompiler" level="${log_resultConverter:-inherited}" />
    <logger name="slick.util.AsyncExecutor"                 level="${log_asyncExecutor:-inherited}" />
</configuration>
```